# Google Maps Stopped working suddenly (Blank Map)

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I am starting with google maps. just learning. while ago, it was working. now it's not. everything seems to work in UI Controls, Markers/Overlay but the map is blank.

```js
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("maps", "2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(103.8, 1.37), 13);
    map.setUIToDefault();
    map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(new google.maps.LatLng(103.8, 1.37)));
});
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/daAiL.png]

Comment: Zoom out and you'll see the map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point you are trying to centre the map onto isn't a valid Lat/Lon pair:  Latitude runs from +/-90 degrees: you're passing in +103.8

seems like you've got your parameters the wrong way around (Lat +1.37, Lon +103.8 puts you in Malaysia)

Comment: Singapore to be more accurate ;)

Comment: This is precisely the problem.  The map isn't blank - it's showing you the location you requested (which is off the map).

Comment: oh, yes i got it wrong. i am supposed to go to singapore. i noticed the precesion is very high i rounded the lat & long to 2 dp and i went far off where i wanted to be ... lol